# Append file javascript with a fixed line names

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I want to output some data using this javascript code:

```
for (var l = 0; l < table.length; l +=1) {
    fs.appendFile('results/Test'+ username +'.csv', var1+i, var2 , function(err) {
      if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
    });
};
```

This code output a csv file like:

```
1    0.5
2    0.3
3    1.0
4    0.9
....
```

However, I want a fixed first line header (Time Values) like:

```
Time Values
 1    0.5
 2    0.3
 3    1.0
 4    0.9
 ....
```

Is there any suggestion ?

Comment: Can you show the full JS function. Hope this is inside a loop. Cant you append this header and then enter into loop ?

Comment: Yes @Rigin it's inside a loop

Comment: Can you write down that loop also here

Comment: `for (var l = 0; l < table.length; l +=1) {  fs.appendFile('results/Test'+ username +'.csv', var1, var2 , function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
});      };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Cant we append this heading before the loop starts ( Hope we are aware of the Header that comes) ?

```
fs.appendFile('results/Test'+ username +'.csv', 'Time','Values');

for (var l = 0; l < table.length; l +=1) {
        fs.appendFile('results/Test'+ username +'.csv', var1+i, var2 , function(err) {
          if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
          }
        });
    };
```

Let me know wheathr my understanding is right or not